# IE 11: Element with min-height: 100vh will cause scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, internet-explorer-11

I already read a lot of posts about IE 11 with display: flex and min-height, but didn't find my answer.

I have a normal `<div>` with a `min-height: 100vh;`. In that `<div>` I have another element with a `margin-bottom: 5px;`. Now the whole outer `<div>` has a scrollbar and a transparent border at the bottom of 5px.

When I increase the margin, the gap at the bottom will increase the same.

Example:

```
<div class="layout">
   <div class="panel">
      Some content
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="panel">
    Panel
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I made the code snipper, I see it also going wrong in Chrome.

I hope you understand me, but if you need more info please ask. I hope to find an answer!

Thank you,
Ronald.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because of [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and it could be fixed in different ways.

Depending on your case, easiest is to use overflow: hidden for .layout:

```
.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You could also use padding-bottom on .layout instead of margin-bottom on .panel to avoid the issue with margins.

Another option could be clearfixing the .layout like so:

```
.layout:before,
.layout:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: There was a space problem. problem is solved. It worked very well on me. The cause of the problem;  overflow: hidden;  should be used . Thenks bro .